# Tabbed navigation using mvvmcross and xamarin forms

Tags: tabs, xamarin.forms, mvvmcross

I am trying to create tabbed app using mvvmcross and xamarin forms, but I can not get rid of main Navigation(Title) bar. I did research and if I have got it right, I will have to create my own presenter. I base my oppinion on this link.

https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/ViewModel--to-ViewModel-navigation

Site redirect me to article "Presenter roundup". Unfortunately I couldn't figure out the solution.

[My problem looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d93gH.png)

Thanks for response.

PS: While answering please keep in mind that I am new to Xamarin and MVVMCross :)

Edit 1:

```
public class App : MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels.MvxApplication
{
    public override void Initialize ()
    {
        CreatableTypes ()
            .EndingWith ("Service")
            .AsInterfaces ()
            .RegisterAsLazySingleton();

        RegisterAppStart<ViewModels.TabbedViewModel> ();
    }
}
```

Comment: So you just want to get rid of `NavigationBar` displaying the title? Can you also post your `App.cs` codes.

Comment: @abdul Not exactly, as you can see in the picture, there are two navbars. One is with text About, and this one should be there. And other one is empty and shouldn't be there. Also I am not creating empty NavigationBar anywhere in my code. I suspect that presenter wrap page from RegisterAppStart in NavigationPage so that creates empty NavigationBar.

Comment: Override the presenter to not wrap in NavigationPage when using your page type?

Comment: @Cheesebaron Yes, I am trying to. I searched default presenter, but I couldn't find place in code where it is wrapping page.

Comment: Right here: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Forms/blob/master/MvvmCross.Forms.Presenter.Core/MvxFormsPagePresenter.cs#L103

Comment: @Cheesebaron Ohh, thanks!! That's it. I had to be blind to not see that :D Any way I run into another problem, that is binding ViewModel to Page. Since TabbedPage does not use "buttons" with commands, but page instances. I would be really glad for any tips or suggestions.